# How do I add a new entry using dexie.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, indexeddb, dexie

Using Dexie I'm trying to add a new entry but I can only get it to add if I specify the id number. I want the id to be auto incremented as its the primary key, how do I achieve this?

**This works**

```
var db = new Dexie("user-database");
db.version(1).stores({
    users: "id++"
});
db.open(); 
var insert_data = {id:5,name: "Paul", email: "test@test.com", user_group: 2};
db.users.add(insert_data);
```

But if I take out the id from the insert object it doesn't work. See below

**This doesn't work**

```
var db = new Dexie("user-database");
db.version(1).stores({
    users: "id++"
});
db.open(); 
var insert_data = {name: "Paul", email: "test@test.com", user_group: 2};
db.users.add(insert_data);</code>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try using `++id` instead of `id++`

Comment: here https://jsfiddle.net/ks7Laacs/3/ check the indexeddb after you run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id` will be appended check it.

**screenshot:**
[image: screenshot of inserted data]

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ks7Laacs/8/)**

**html:**

```
Name:<input type="text" name="name" id="name"/><br/>
Email<input type="text" name="email" id="email"/></br>
<button>add new</button>
```

**javascript:**

```
// Declare db instance
var db = new Dexie("test-database");

// Define Database Schema
db.version(1).stores({
    users: "++id, name, email"
});

// Open Database
db.open(); 

function add_new(name,email){
    // Interact With Database
    db.transaction('rw', db.users, function () {
        // Let's add some data to db:
        insert_object = {name:name,email:email};
        db.users.add(insert_object);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.error(err.stack || err);
    });    
}

add_new("susheel singh","susheel61@gmail.com");//default content
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click",function(e){
    add_new(document.getElementById("name").value,document.getElementById("email").value);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You would have to delete the database before redefining another schema.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dfahlander/eb9yt0s7/

```
var db = new Dexie("test-database");
db.version(1).stores({
    users: 'id,name,email'
});
document.write ('hello');
db.delete().then(function (){
  return db.open ();
}).then (function (){
  var insert_object = {id:2,name:'Bob',email:'test@test.com'};
  return db.users.add(insert_object);
}).then(function(){
    return db.delete (); // don't forget to delete if changing prim key
}).then (function (){
    db = new Dexie("test-database");
    db.version(1).stores({
        users: 'id++'
    });
    return db.open();
}).then(function (){
    var insert_object = {name:'Jim',email:'jim@test.com'};
    db.users.add(insert_object);
}).then(function (){
   return db.users.toArray();
}).then (function (result){
  document.write(JSON.stringify (result));
}).catch (function (e) {
  document.write ('error: ' + e);
});
```

If you weren't changing the primary key, but just adding or removing indices, you could have closed the db and then added db.version (2) with the changes indexes or added /removed tables.